# RecyclerView : movie image not displaying

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, imageview

I am trying to get the data using asynctaskloader and display the images in a fragment using recyclerview.
Previously i did this, then i did not get the error.I am not sure why this is happening.

but i image is not daisplaying

when i used picasso this is the one i got in logcat

```
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R4] Request{http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/8UlWHLMpgZm9bx6QYh0NFoq67TZ.jpg}
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R4]+1ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R4]+2ms 
D/Picasso: Main        created      [R5] Request{http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/dWSnsAGTfc8U27bWsy2RfwZs0Bs.jpg}
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R5]+1ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R5]+1ms 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xddc5e660: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe3e7ec40)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xddc5e660: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe3e7ec40)
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  retrying     [R4]+612ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R4]+612ms 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  retrying     [R5]+609ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R5]+609ms 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  retrying     [R5]+1167ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R5]+1168ms 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  retrying     [R4]+1175ms 
D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R4]+1176ms 
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  batched      [R5]+1171ms for error
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  batched      [R4]+1179ms for error
D/Picasso: Dispatcher  delivered    [R5]+1413ms, [R4]+1419ms 
D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R5]+1413ms HTTP 504
D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R4]+1419ms HTTP 504
```

Fragment classs:

```
package com.example.srilakshmibomireddy.movies

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.content.Loader
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import android.widget.Toast
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.util.ArrayList

class Popular : Fragment(),android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String>{
    val popular:String = "popular"
    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var layoutManager:GridLayoutManager
    val list = ArrayList<MoviesData>()
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_popular, container, false)
        val inputMethodManager = activity!!.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
        val connectivityManager = activity!!.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected && activity != null) {
            GetMovies(context!!,popular)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "please check network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.popular_posters)
        layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
        layoutManager.setOrientation(GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        val moviesadapter = MoviesAdapter(context!!)
        moviesadapter.movieslist = list
        recyclerView.adapter = moviesadapter
        loaderManager.initLoader(0, null, this)
        return view
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val connectivityManager = activity!!.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected) {
            GetMovies(context!!,popular)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "please check network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    override fun onCreateLoader(p0: Int, p1: Bundle?): Loader<String> {
        return  GetMovies(context!!,popular)
    }

    override fun onLoaderReset(p0: Loader<String>) {

    }

    override fun onLoadFinished(p0: Loader<String>, data: String?) {
        val moviesadapter = MoviesAdapter(context!!)
        if (data == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No Data Fetched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }
        try {
            val jsonObject = JSONObject(data)
            val jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results")
            for (i in 0 until jsonArray1.length()) {
                val jsonObject1 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i)
                val title = jsonObject1.getString("title")
                val popularity = jsonObject1.getString("popularity")
                val poster = jsonObject1.optString("poster_path").toString()
                val orgTitle = jsonObject1.getString("original_title")
                val release = jsonObject1.getString("release_date")
                val overview = jsonObject1.getString("overview")
                val rating = jsonObject1.getString("vote_average")
                val id = jsonObject1.getString("id")
                val moviesdata = MoviesData(title, popularity, poster, orgTitle, release, overview, rating, id)
                list.add(moviesdata)
            }
            moviesadapter.movieslist = list
            recyclerView.adapter = moviesadapter
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
```

}

fragment resource file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.srilakshmibomireddy.moviesdetailsapp.Fragments.Popular">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        android:id="@+id/popular_posters"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

MyAdapter:

```
package com.example.srilakshmibomireddy.movies

import android.content.Context
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

class MoviesAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    var context: Context
    var movieslist: List<MoviesData>? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }

    constructor(context: Context) : super() {
        this.context = context
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return movieslist!!.size
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var moviedata : MoviesData = movieslist!!.get(position)
        var s : String ="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342".plus(moviedata.poster)
        Toast.makeText(context,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        Picasso.get().load(s).into(holder.movie_poster)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): MyViewHolder {
        var view :View = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.movies_adapter,p0,false)
        return  MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    class MyViewHolder(view :View) :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var movie_poster : ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster)
    }
}
```

Adapter resource file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movie_poster"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/movie_poster"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am using "Http" when i had to use "Https" in the image link

Changing

```
var s : String ="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342".plus(moviedata.poster)
```

to

```
var s : String ="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342".plus(moviedata.poster)
```

solved my issue